# MySQL QUERY: JOIN multiple tables with ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
SELECT
    FRIEND.friend_two AS possible_friend, USERS.username AS possible_username
FROM
    user_friends FRIEND, users USERS
WHERE 
    FRIEND.friend_one IN (SELECT friend_two FROM user_friends WHERE friend_one = :id)
    AND FRIEND.friend_two NOT IN (SELECT friend_two FROM user_friends WHERE friend_one = :id)
    AND NOT FRIEND.friend_two = :id
GROUP BY possible_friend
```

users

```
+------------+------------------+
|     id     |     username     |
+------------+------------------+
|     10     |       Josh       |
+------------+------------------+
|     20     |     Steward      |
+------------+------------------+
|     30     |      Fenton      | 
+------------+------------------+
```

user_friends

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| friend_id  | friend_one | friend_two |    Role    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ramdom_id  |     10     |     10     |     me     +
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ramdom_id  |     20     |     20     |     me     +
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ramdom_id  |     10     |     20     |   friend   +
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ramdom_id  |     20     |     30     |   friend   +
+------------+------------+------------+------------+

friend_one = 10 (Josh)      -> follows -> friend_two = 20 (Steward)
friend_one = 20 (Steward)   -> follows -> friend_two = 30 (Fenton)
```

var_dump($query); displays the following text.

```
Array ( [possible_friend] => 30 [possible_username] => STEWARD )
```

The error in the var_dump is that I already follow Steward, and Steward has an id of (20). What I'd like to show is

```
Array ( [possible_friend] => 30 [possible_username] => FENTON )
```

Since Fenton has an id of `(30)` and `Josh(10)` who is logged in is not following Fenton.

If `Josh(10)` is logged in, it'll suggest `JOSH` to follow `Fenton(30)` since `Steward(20)` follows `Fenton(30)` while `Josh(10)` does not.

When this query comes to closure, it's purpose is to suggest Friends of my Friends for the user to follow as explained above.

How do I use GROUP BY to make sure that the user that's being suggested has the correct username being printed as I explained with the var_dump for FENTON.
As of the moment it's retrieving random usernames of users that I already follow and not by 'AS possible_friends' in the query.

---

Comment: Oh my goodness, I think I started seeing stars reading that. Can you add an edit explaining what you want it to do, in just plain english. Don't worry about code or structure - I think it is clouding the answer. Based on your users and user_friends table, what do you want it do? if I am understanding it, something to suggest friends based on other friends's friends?

Comment: I'd like to accomplish exactly like twitter's friend suggestion, does that make it simple enough or should I give a better explanation?

Comment: There seems to be nothing about `UNION` in your post. Have you meant `JOIN`?

Comment: Is the USERS.user_id the parameter you are sending for :id

Comment: Ops, It's JOIN I'm sorry! @PM77-1 
Yes Irb

Comment: @iBrazilian I don't do twitter. Do you want it to suggest friends for a user based on friends of their friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that nothing in your query actually puts any restrictions on the `USERS` rows to be returned, so you're joining each relevant row of `USER_FRIENDS` to *all* rows of `USERS`, and then leaving it to the `GROUP BY` to select one arbitrarily.

The best fix is to change this:

```
FROM
    user_friends FRIEND, users USERS
```

to this:

```
FROM user_friends friend
JOIN users
  ON users.id = friend.friend_two
```

to specify that you're specifically looking for the row of `USERS` whose `id` matches the `friend_two` of the relevant `USER_FRIENDS` row.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I spend a few hours trying join and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach you might consider:

```
SELECT FRIEND_NAME.username, P_FRIEND_NAME.username
FROM user_friends FRIENDS 
INNER JOIN user_friends P_FRIENDS on FRIENDS.friend_one = P_FRIENDS.friend_two
INNER JOIN users FRIEND_NAME on FRIENDS.friend_two = FRIEND_NAME.id
INNER JOIN users P_FRIEND_NAME on P_FRIENDS.friend_one = P_FRIEND_NAME.id
WHERE FRIENDS.friend_one <> P_FRIENDS.friend_one
and FRIENDS.friend_two <> P_FRIENDS.friend_two
```

Results:
Fenton | Josh